# How to create an Outlook email template in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React.js, I want to create an email template for a mail that's going to be sent with Outlook, I'm currently struggling with librairies"mjml-react" and "nextmail react". the content of the email is displayed and it contains all the html tags.
Does anyone have an example that can work ?

```
const emailHTML = renderEmail(
    <Email title="Hello World!">
      <Item>
        <Span>
          This is an example email made with
        </Span>
      </Item>
    </Email>)

var addresses = "";
var body = emailHTML;

var subject = "subjects"
var href = "mailto:" + addresses + "?"
         + "subject=" + subject + "&"
         + "body=" + body;
var wndMail;
window.location.href=href;
```

Comment: Any breakthrough with this request? I'm also interested in doing something like this